# Move a object within the canvas after scaling and rotating fabrics

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, fabricjs

I am able to move a object within the canvas boundary when it is rotated / scaled. Pls see the following fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/JtRhX/33/

Problem step:

1. scale the image > than the canvas width/height.
2. Problem1: Try to move the obj by just 1px in any direction, the obj will immediately go to the other end cause of object:moving event
3. Problem2: after scaling the image the the moving of the obj is also inverse.

Im using the following code to check for he border positioning on top , similarly for bot

```
if(obj.getBoundingRect().top < 0 || obj.getBoundingRect().left < 0){
    obj.top = Math.max(obj.top, obj.top-obj.getBoundingRect().top);
    obj.left = Math.max(obj.left, obj.left-obj.getBoundingRect().left);
}
```

Comment: What it is the expected behavior when the image is bigger than the canvas?

Answer (score 0):

For the comments in the fiddle's code

> // if object is too big ignore

it seems that you want to allow going over the edges of the canvas in that situation.

If so, you just need to change this line:

```
if(obj.currentHeight > obj.canvas.height || obj.currentWidth > obj.canvas.width) {
```

for this one:

```
if(obj.getBoundingRect().height > canvas.height || obj.getBoundingRect().width > obj.canvas.width) {
```

Please note that both `obj.currentHeight` and `obj.currentWidth` are *undefined*.

Hope it helps!

Comment: What i need is , suppose i increase the width of obj greater than canvas and move the obj left / right , the obj should lock at the left/right edge as it is doing in my example.

Comment: But when the object is bigger than the canvas, it has already passed through one edge. In that case you want to lock just the opposite one, don't you? And, what happen if the user, while making the object bigger, overflow both sides?

Comment: Just try making the object bigger than canvas and move the object. I need the same behaviour , but with the points mentioned in the question.